# Cronjob command is not working

Tags: perforce, cron

I have one script that I am trying to set as crontab, but it is failing at "p4 sync" statement.

Getting following error :

```
/bin/sh: 1: p4: not found
```

I can run it manually without any errors.

I tries adding full path:

```
 /usr/local/bin/p4 sync
```

Still not working.

Any clue what i am missing?? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ofcource its perforce a command. :)

Comment: What's the error message when you use the full path? If still the same, you need to find the correct path to use.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variable ?

You may try to add this:

```
. /etc/profile   
source $yourHomePath/.bash_profile   
source $yourHomePath/.bashrc
```

This is used to add user's profile into path.